# sed not finding '0A' control character

Tags: linux, sed

The file contains a carriage return line feed sequence hex 'DA'. Hexedit clearly shows the two hex characters.

```
20 0D 0A 31
```

and

```
sed  -n '/\x0D/p' ./test.txt
```

Clearly identifies the lines
However

```
sed  -n '/\x0A/p' ./test.txt
```

does not find any lines.

To make this even more interesting after using sed to remove the '0D' it did not find the '0A' in the string:

```
20 0A 31
```

How can sed be used to remove 0D0A after a specific character string. The file has extraneous line feeds after specific text. This creates 2 lines where there should be one. The objective is to recreate one one from two.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline . Use `dos2unix`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Good tip in general, but the OP wants to "remove 0D0A [only] _after a specific character string_."

Answer (score 4):

`sed` reads the input line by line; lines are separated by `\x0a`.

You can use Perl instead, `-0777` reads the whole file, not line by line:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\x0d\x0a//'
```

Answer (score 4):

In `sed`, unlike say python, the newline character `\n` is considered a *line separator* and *not* part of any line.  If you want to modify the newline characters, read the whole file in at once and then do your substitutions:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/something\n/somethingelse/g'
```

#### How it works

`sed` has both a pattern space (where newly-read lines go) and a hold space.  These commands append the newly-read lines to the hold space until we reach the last line.  Then the whole of the file is transferred to the pattern space and you can do whatever commands on it that you wish.  In detail:

- `H` - Append current line to hold space
- `1h`  - If this is the first line, overwrite the hold space
  with it
- `$!d` - If this is not the last line, delete pattern space
  and jump to the next line.
- `x`  - Exchange hold and pattern space to put whole file in
  pattern space

#### Example

Let's consider this sample file:

```
$ cat file
Try to av-
oid word
splits.
```

Now, let's merge any line that ends with a hyphen with the line that follows:

```
$ sed 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/-\n//g' file
Try to avoid word
splits.
```

Or, if you prefer the hex form:

```
$ sed 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/-\x0a//g' file2
Try to avoid word
splits.
```